# Adding Multiple Header Rows to Telerik RadGrid

Tags: header, radgrid

I'm using Telerik RadGrid and have a requirement which I was able to achieve but it seems to not work in the manner I expected.

Requirement :
Add a Parent Header row on one button click (Load 5 Records) and remove on another button click (Load More Records)

[image: Multiple Header Rows]

The Grid declaration is as below

```
                            <telerik:RadGrid ID="rgDetails1" runat="server" Width="99.9%" Skin="Office2010Blue"
                                EnableEmbeddedSkins="true" AutoGenerateColumns="true" OnColumnCreated="rgDetails1_ColumnCreated">
                                <MasterTableView DataKeyNames="RowID" TableLayout="Fixed" HeaderStyle-Height="28px">
                                    <NoRecordsTemplate>
                                        <asp:Label ID="lblError" runat="server" Text="No records to display."></asp:Label></NoRecordsTemplate>
                                </MasterTableView>
                                <ClientSettings>
                                    <Resizing AllowColumnResize="True" />
                                    <Scrolling AllowScroll="true" ScrollHeight="280px" UseStaticHeaders="true"></Scrolling>
                                    <ClientEvents OnGridCreated="GridCreated" />
                                </ClientSettings>
                            </telerik:RadGrid>
```

and the Grid is bound with below codes

```
protected void btnLoad1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable fdtObjDetails = null;
    try
    {
        fdtObjDetails = LoadData(5);

        GridColumnGroup parentHeader = new GridColumnGroup();
        parentHeader.HeaderText = "Essential";
        parentHeader.Name = "Group1";
        parentHeader.HeaderStyle.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Center;
        rgDetails1.MasterTableView.ColumnGroups.Add(parentHeader);

        rgDetails1.DataSource = fdtObjDetails;
        rgDetails1.DataBind();
    }
    catch (Exception objExcep)
    {
        string fstrError = objExcep.ToString();
    }
}
```

and on Column Created event of the RadGrid grouping is done.

```
protected void rgDetails1_ColumnCreated(object sender, GridColumnCreatedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (e.Column.HeaderText != "" && e.Column.HeaderText != string.Empty && e.Column.HeaderText != null)
            {
                e.Column.ItemStyle.Height = System.Web.UI.WebControls.Unit.Pixel(20);
                switch (e.Column.HeaderText.ToUpper())
                {
                    case "ROWID":
                    case "ROW ID":
                        e.Column.Visible = false;
                        break;

                    case "TYPE":
                        e.Column.HeaderText = "Type";
                        e.Column.UniqueName = "Type";
                        e.Column.HeaderStyle.Width = System.Web.UI.WebControls.Unit.Pixel(100);
                        e.Column.HeaderStyle.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Center;
                        e.Column.HeaderStyle.VerticalAlign = VerticalAlign.Middle;
                        e.Column.ColumnGroupName = "Group1";
                        break;

                    case "FLIGHT NAME":
                    case "FLIGHT_NAME":
                        {
                            e.Column.HeaderText = "Flight Name";
                            e.Column.UniqueName = "Flight_Name";
                            e.Column.HeaderStyle.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Center;
                            e.Column.HeaderStyle.VerticalAlign = VerticalAlign.Middle;
                            e.Column.ColumnGroupName = "Group1";
                            break;
                        }

                    case "LIVES":
                        {
                            e.Column.HeaderText = "Lives";
                            e.Column.UniqueName = "Lives";
                            GridBoundColumn _GridColumn = (GridBoundColumn)e.Column;
                            e.Column.HeaderStyle.Width = System.Web.UI.WebControls.Unit.Pixel(60);
                            e.Column.HeaderStyle.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Center;
                            e.Column.ItemStyle.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Right;
                            e.Column.HeaderStyle.VerticalAlign = VerticalAlign.Middle;
                            _GridColumn.DataFormatString = "{0:#,###}";
                            e.Column.ColumnGroupName = "Group1";
                            break;
                        }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception objExcep)
        {
            string fstrClsNm = "AL-CLS" + this.GetType().BaseType.FullName + "-rgDetails1_ColumnCreated()";
        }
    }
```

Now the problem is, as soon as I click any one of the buttons I get the below error.

[image]

How do I resolve this? or is there any other way to add Header Rows which looks similar to the image above?

Comment: you have issues in ur code? or you need a different design from the pic which you posted?

Comment: Thanks Balaji for the reply. As far as I know, Telerik says we can't have the Grid structure in ASPX and add the grouping dynamically at run time. They suggest either have the Grid and Grouping in ASPX or create the grid dynamically in code-behind at run-time. I wanted to know if there is any other option available. I need the same design as in the picture.